# Arrow pointing to subscript in equation

Tags: equations, arrows, labels, tikz-arrows

I'm writing an equation for the components of a contracted tensor. I want to label one of the lower (covariant) indices with the text "rth positon," and have an arrow pointing to it from below. Any way to do this easily?

Something like this:

> [image]

I'd also like to be able to do something like this from above so I can label upper (contravariant) indices.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you give an approximate graphic representation of what you're looking for?

Comment: Which package are you using to produce the indices for the tensor?

Comment: Please provide a little example! Like this we know what documentclass you are using and we do not have to type the formula.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's an example using the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library for TikZ; there was no information in the question regarding how the formula was typeset, but the idea will still apply: place marks using `\tikzmark` and then use the marks to draw the arrows and place the accompanying texts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\[
A_{1\ldots\tikzmark{a}p\ldots\tikzmark{b}q\ldots4}
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[<-] 
  ([shift={(2pt,-2pt)}]pic cs:a) |- ([shift={(-10pt,-10pt)}]pic cs:a) 
  node[anchor=east] {$\scriptstyle a\text{th position}$}; 
\draw[<-] 
  ([shift={(2pt,-2pt)}]pic cs:b) |- ([shift={(14pt,-10pt)}]pic cs:b) 
  node[anchor=west] {$\scriptstyle b\text{th position}$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If, for some reason, the `tikzmark` library is not available, then one can use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\coordinate (#1);}

\begin{document}

\[
A_{1\ldots\tikzmark{a}p\ldots\tikzmark{b}q\ldots4}
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[<-] 
  ([shift={(2pt,-2pt)}]a) |- ([shift={(-10pt,-10pt)}]a) 
  node[anchor=east] {$\scriptstyle a\text{th position}$}; 
\draw[<-] 
  ([shift={(2pt,-2pt)}]b) |- ([shift={(14pt,-10pt)}]b) 
  node[anchor=west] {$\scriptstyle b\text{th position}$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I'm looking for. However, when I try to use your example, I get the error message: ! I can't find file `tikzlibrarytikzmark.code.tex'.
<argument> ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex
                                                  \catcode `\@ =\csname tikz...
l.14 \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
                              
Please type another input file name:

Comment: @user59001 You're welcome! In order for my code to work you need an updated LaTeX system. In the meantime, I can provide a modified version in some minutes, not requiring the library.

Comment: @user59001 please see my updated answer. The second version of the code should work even with outdated versions of PGF/TikZ.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler, yet not exactly identical, solution without using `tikz` is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{c}
    A_{1\ldots pq\ldots4}\\
    \;\;\swarrow\;\searrow\\
    a\mbox{th position}\qquad b\mbox{th position}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using stacks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{p,q}g^{pq}A_{1\ldots 
\stackengine{2pt}
  {\scriptstyle p}
  {\scriptstyle\text{$a$th position}\rule[1pt]{2ex}{.5pt}\mkern-5mu\raisebox{1.1pt}
  {\stackon[-.1pt]{\rule{.5pt}{9.1pt}}{\uparrow}}}{U}{r}{F}{T}{S}
\ldots 
\stackengine{2pt}
  {\scriptstyle q}
  {\scriptstyle\raisebox{1.1pt}{\stackon[-.1pt]{\rule{.5pt}{9.1pt}}{\uparrow}}
  \mkern-5mu\rule[1pt]{2ex}{.5pt}\text{$b$th position}}{U}{l}{F}{T}{S}
\ldots4}^{i_1\ldots i_r}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]