# Fix arrows from equation to text

Tags: equations, tikz-arrows

I was attempting to get this effect on my equation:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,,arrows,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\tikz[baseline]{\node(d13) {$\hat{\underline{\theta}}_{k+1}$}} = \tikz[baseline]{\node(d14){$\hat{\underline{\theta}}_{k}$}} + P_{k+1}\dfrac{h_{k+1}}{\sigma^{2}_{k+1}}(y_{k+1}-h'_{k+1}\hat{\underline{\theta}}_{k})
\end{equation*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]{
   \draw[red,thick,->] (d13) to [in=90,out=235] +(240:2cm) node[anchor=west,text = black,] {$current~estimate$};
    \draw[red,thick,->] (d14) to [in=90,out=235] +(290:1cm) node[anchor=west,text = black,] {$previous~estimate$};}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you look http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191217/arrow-pointing-to-subscript-in-equation?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Version 1:

I don't know what precisely you want to change, but maybe the following can be a starting point for further improvements:

```
\begin{equation*}
\tikz[baseline]{\node(d13) {$\hat{\underline{\theta}}_{k+1}$}} = \tikz[baseline]{\node(d14){$\hat{\underline{\theta}}_{k}$}} + P_{k+1}\dfrac{h_{k+1}}{\sigma^{2}_{k+1}}(y_{k+1}-h'_{k+1}\hat{\underline{\theta}}_{k})
\end{equation*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]{
   \draw[red,thick,->] (d14) to [in=180,out=270] +(310:2cm) node[anchor=west,text = black,] (label1) {previous estimate};
   \draw[red,thick,->] (d13) to [in=180,out=270] ($(label1.west)-(0,1cm)$) node[anchor=west,text = black] {current estimate};}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: output]

Some remarks:

1. If the arrows should leave towards the bottom, then you need `out=270`.
2. If the arrows should enter at the labels from the left, then you need `in=180` (both numbers are counterclockwise degrees)
3. To have the label to the right, you should choose a direction between 270 and 360 (I chose 310 below).
4. To have the lower label directly below the upper label, I gave the first label a name and added a coordinate computation `($...$)`; see the tikz manual for more information.
5. The labels should not be enclosed with `$`, since the labels consist of text, not of math.

### Version 2:

Straight lines can be drawn with `--` (or with `to` and without `in=` nor `out=`), and the corners can be rounded with `rounded corners` (an optional argument determines the radius of the rounding; see the manual).  Instead of specifying an additional node, you can also use the path specification `|-` for a path that is first vertical and then horizontal.

```
\begin{equation*}
\tikz[baseline]{\node(d13) {$\hat{\underline{\theta}}_{k+1}$}} = \tikz[baseline]{\node(d14){$\hat{\underline{\theta}}_{k}$}} + P_{k+1}\dfrac{h_{k+1}}{\sigma^{2}_{k+1}}(y_{k+1}-h'_{k+1}\hat{\underline{\theta}}_{k})
\end{equation*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]{
   \draw[red,thick,->,rounded corners] (d14) |- ++ (1cm,-2cm) node[anchor=west,text = black,] (label1) {previous estimate};
   \draw[red,thick,->,rounded corners] (d13) |- ($(label1.west)-(0,1cm)$) node[anchor=west,text = black] {current~estimate};}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: output 2]