# How can I create an effect for my equation in beamer class?

Tags: beamer, overlays

I am doing a presentation in the beamer class and I would like that one of my equations to have an effect in which the comments on each of the terms slowly they arose, with the figures below. However, I don't know how to do that. How can I create such an effect?

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,compress,mathserif,serif,t]{beamer}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Chern-Simons baby Skyrme model}\framesubtitle{The model and its equations of motion}

\only<1>{The baby Skyrme model%
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}=\dfrac{\nu^{2}}{2}\partial_{\mu}\boldsymbol{\phi}\cdot
\partial^{\mu}\boldsymbol{\phi}-\dfrac{\lambda^{2}}{4}\left(  \partial_{\mu
}\boldsymbol{\phi}\times\partial_{\nu}\boldsymbol{\phi}\right)  \cdot\left(
\partial^{\mu}\boldsymbol{\phi}\times\partial^{\nu}\boldsymbol{\phi}\right)
-V\left(  \boldsymbol{\hat{n}}\cdot\boldsymbol{\phi}\right)  \label{S1A0}%
\end{equation}
is (1+2)-dimensional a non-linear theory that provides
\alert{topological solitons}.}

\only<2>{The baby Skyrme model%
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}=\underbrace{\dfrac{\nu^{2}}{2}\partial_{\mu}\boldsymbol{\phi}%
\cdot\partial^{\mu}\boldsymbol{\phi}}_{\text{sigma}}-\underbrace{\dfrac
{\lambda^{2}}{4}\left(  \partial_{\mu}\boldsymbol{\phi}\times\partial_{\nu
}\boldsymbol{\phi}\right)  \cdot\left(  \partial^{\mu}\boldsymbol{\phi}%
\times\partial^{\nu}\boldsymbol{\phi}\right)  }_{\text{Skyrme}}%
-\underbrace{V\left(  \boldsymbol{\hat{n}}\cdot\boldsymbol{\phi}\right)
}_{\text{potencial}}%
\end{equation}
is (1+2)-dimensional a non-linear theory that provides
\alert{topological solitons}.}

\only<3>{The baby Skyrme model%
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}=\overbrace{\underbrace{\dfrac{\nu^{2}}{2}\partial_{\mu
}\boldsymbol{\phi}\cdot\partial^{\mu}\boldsymbol{\phi}}_{\text{sigma}%
}-\underbrace{\dfrac{\lambda^{2}}{4}\left(  \partial_{\mu}\boldsymbol{\phi
}\times\partial_{\nu}\boldsymbol{\phi}\right)  \cdot\left(  \partial^{\mu
}\boldsymbol{\phi}\times\partial^{\nu}\boldsymbol{\phi}\right)  }%
_{\text{Skyrme}}}^{U\left(  1\right)  \text{ and }SO\left(  3\right)  \text{
invariant}}-\underbrace{\overbrace{V\left(  \boldsymbol{\hat{n}}%
\cdot\boldsymbol{\phi}\right)  }^{\substack{U\left(  1\right)  \text{
invariant}\\S0\left(  3\right)  \text{ partially breaking}}}}%
_{\text{potencial}}%
\end{equation}
is (1+2)-dimensional a non-linear theory that provides
\alert{topological solitons}.}\pause
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Update:

I have tried the following solution, but there is still something to be improved:

```
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Chern-Simons baby Skyrme model}

\framesubtitle{The model and its equations of motion}
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=+.5ex]
The baby Skyrme model
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}=\only<1>{\dfrac{\nu^{2}}{2}\partial_{\mu}\boldsymbol{\phi}\cdot
\partial^{\mu}\boldsymbol{\phi}-\dfrac{\lambda^{2}}{4}\left(  \partial_{\mu
}\boldsymbol{\phi}\times\partial_{\nu}\boldsymbol{\phi}\right)  \cdot\left(
\partial^{\mu}\boldsymbol{\phi}\times\partial^{\nu}\boldsymbol{\phi}\right)-V\left(  \boldsymbol{\hat{n}}\cdot\boldsymbol{\phi}\right)}%
            \only<2>{\tikz[baseline]{\node(t1){$\underbrace{\dfrac{\nu^{2}}{2}\partial_{\mu}\boldsymbol{\phi}\cdot
\partial^{\mu}\boldsymbol{\phi}}$}}-\tikz[baseline]{\node(t2){$\underbrace{\dfrac{\lambda^{2}}{4}\left(  \partial_{\mu
}\boldsymbol{\phi}\times\partial_{\nu}\boldsymbol{\phi}\right)  \cdot\left(
\partial^{\mu}\boldsymbol{\phi}\times\partial^{\nu}\boldsymbol{\phi}\right)}$}}-\tikz[baseline]{\node(t3){$\underbrace{V\left(  \boldsymbol{\hat{n}}\cdot\boldsymbol{\phi}\right)}$}}}%
            \only<3>{\tikz[baseline]{\node(t4){$\overbrace{\tikz[baseline]{\node(t1){$\underbrace{\dfrac{\nu^{2}}{2}\partial_{\mu}\boldsymbol{\phi}\cdot
\partial^{\mu}\boldsymbol{\phi}}$}}-\tikz[baseline]{\node(t2){$\underbrace{\dfrac{\lambda^{2}}{4}\left(  \partial_{\mu
}\boldsymbol{\phi}\times\partial_{\nu}\boldsymbol{\phi}\right)  \cdot\left(
\partial^{\mu}\boldsymbol{\phi}\times\partial^{\nu}\boldsymbol{\phi}\right)}$}}}$}}-\tikz[baseline]{\node(t5){$\overbrace{\tikz[baseline]{\node(t3){$\underbrace{V\left(  \boldsymbol{\hat{n}}\cdot\boldsymbol{\phi}\right)}$}}}$}}}%
\end{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]{
   \draw[] (t5) node[anchor=south,text = black]{$\substack{ U\left(  1\right)\text{
invariant}\\S0\left( 3\right)  \text{ partially breaking}}$};
   \draw[] (t4) node[anchor=south ,text = black]{$U\left(1\right)$ and $SO\left(3\right)$ invariant};
   \draw[] (t3) node[anchor=north,text = black]{potential};
   \draw[] (t2) node[anchor=north,text = black]{Skyrme};
   \draw[] (t1) node[anchor=north,text = black]{sigma model};}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Can you please explain better what you want? Do you want these elements to fade in?

Comment: Try to use `\only<2->{…}` or `\visible<2->{…}` inside the equations.

Comment: Side note, how is this related to `tikz` ?

Comment: @BambOo clearly because it is _not_ a drawing!

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks for answering. That's not well this what I want. What I want is that the elements arose in the order of the figures above presented. The idea is that, at the first moment, I just show the equation. And then I will presented each one term of these terms in the Lagrangian and, at this moment, I want the comments below to arise, as in the second figure. Then I will explain a little about the symmetry invariance of terms and at this point, I want to dirty the comments as in figure 3.

Comment: so what about `\only<1>{x}\only<2->{\underbrace{x}_{text}}`?

Comment: @BambOo One alternative would be to implement the same idea with tikz as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278263 or in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86188/178782 .

Comment: With the ocgx2 package, it is possible to make elements clickable with the mouse. One click makes the text visible, another makes it invisible. On the other hand, it does not allow a progressive display, nor a progressive erasing. It works at the click of the mouse.

Comment: @Faekynn: Could you explain your comment about it *not* being a drawing, and that somehow makes it a TikZ question? I do not want to start an argument here in the comments, but let us correct the tags.

Comment: @Faekynn : same problem than hpekristiansen, shat do you  mean with "it not being a drawing" ?

Comment: @hpekristiansen oh it was just a joke (tikz= tikz is not a drawing program/ tikz ist kein zeichenprogramm). Clearly, an equation is not a drawing, so tikz is the right thing :) back to being serious, of course I also think the tag is wrong.

Comment: I would like to disagree with you. Even though I'm using the \underbrae and \overbrace in the equation, I could perfectly use arrows pointing to comments at timely locations. And of course, I could do that using tikz. The question here is how could I do this and at the same time implement the overlays so that I get an effect that has the result I want.

Comment: Unrelated grammatical remark: it should be *potential* rather than *potencial*.

Comment: @egg So, of course, It was a misconception due to the similarity with the Portuguese.